# Forwarding requests to another Azure Container App in the same environment results in 403 forbidden

Tags: networking, azure, azure-networking, caddy

**-- Copied from Stackoverflow --**

I am trying to setup two containers in an Azure Container App Environment. One Container App has a Caddy reverse-proxy plus SPA app files (`app-www`) and another has an Express API with Apollo (`app-api`). `app-api` sits upstream of `app-www` behind the Caddy proxy.

On my local machine Docker instance, this work fine using the localhost and ports for networking. It also works on Azure when I setup ingress on `app-api` using TCP and just the app name for the host in the Caddy config e.g. `http://app-api:5000`. However I cannot use features like the in-built Container App authentication using TCP so I want to configure HTTP ingress and make it secure only.

Using HTTP ingress on `app-api` comes back with a `403 forbidden` when accessing through the reverse-proxy. The following appears in the `app-www` Caddy logs with nothing appearing in the `app-api` logs ...

```
{"level":"debug","ts":1703005543.3806593,"logger":"http.handlers.rewrite","msg":"rewrote request","request":{"remote_ip":"100.100.0.48","remote_port":"56138","proto":"HTTP/1.1","method":"GET","host":"app-www.somerandom-abc123.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io:443","uri":"/tools/evidence/api/content/d8e5a7fd-2330-42ca-949f-b4a5bc5b3dcc.png","headers":{"Authorization":[],"Sec-Ch-Ua":["\"Not_A Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"120\""],"User-Agent":["Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"],"Accept":["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"],"Sec-Fetch-Mode":["navigate"],"Sec-Fetch-Dest":["document"],"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":["1"],"X-K8se-App-Namespace":["k8se-apps"],"X-Arr-Ssl":["true"],"Sec-Fetch-User":["?1"],"X-Envoy-External-Address":["10.0.0.7"],"Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform":["\"macOS\""],"X-Request-Id":["d6d212bd-44f5-4bf8-ac46-9d4c41fc833c"],"X-Ms-Containerapp-Revision-Name":["app-www--3covj1h"],"X-Original-Url":["/tools/evidence/api/content/d8e5a7fd-2330-42ca-949f-b4a5bc5b3dcc.png"],"X-Appgw-Trace-Id":["1df4953e9788544fc1a4ede599a32efc"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip, deflate, br"],"X-Forwarded-For":["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49999,10.0.0.7"],"X-Original-Host":["my-external-url.com"],"Dnt":["1"],"Accept-Language":["en-US,en;q=0.9"],"X-K8se-App-Name":["app-www--3covj1h"],"Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile":["?0"],"X-Envoy-Expected-Rq-Timeout-Ms":["1800000"],"X-K8se-App-Kind":["web"],"X-Ms-Containerapp-Name":["app-www"],"X-Forwarded-Port":["443"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0"],"Sec-Fetch-Site":["none"],"X-K8se-Protocol":["http1"],"X-Forwarded-Proto":["https"]}},"method":"GET","uri":"/content/d8e5a7fd-2330-42ca-949f-b4a5bc5b3dcc.png"},
{"level":"debug","ts":1703005543.380741,"logger":"http.handlers.reverse_proxy","msg":"selected upstream","dial":"app-api.internal.somerandom-abc123.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io:443","total_upstreams":1},
{"level":"debug","ts":1703005543.4035332,"logger":"http.handlers.reverse_proxy","msg":"upstream roundtrip","upstream":"app-api.internal.somerandom-abc123.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io:443","duration":0.022743249,"request":{"remote_ip":"100.100.0.48","remote_port":"56138","proto":"HTTP/1.1","method":"GET","host":"app-www.somerandom-abc123.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io:443","uri":"/content/d8e5a7fd-2330-42ca-949f-b4a5bc5b3dcc.png","headers":{"Authorization":[],"X-Arr-Ssl":["true"],"X-Ms-Containerapp-Revision-Name":["app-www--3covj1h"],"X-Original-Url":["/tools/evidence/api/content/d8e5a7fd-2330-42ca-949f-b4a5bc5b3dcc.png"],"X-Forwarded-Host":["app-www.somerandom-abc123.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io:443"],"Dnt":["1"],"X-Forwarded-For":["100.100.0.48"],"X-Forwarded-Port":["443"],"Sec-Fetch-User":["?1"],"Accept-Language":["en-US,en;q=0.9"],"Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile":["?0"],"Sec-Fetch-Site":["none"],"X-K8se-App-Kind":["web"],"Sec-Ch-Ua":["\"Not_A Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"120\""],"X-Request-Id":["d6d212bd-44f5-4bf8-ac46-9d4c41fc833c"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip, deflate, br"],"X-Ms-Containerapp-Name":["app-www"],"X-K8se-Protocol":["http1"],"X-Forwarded-Proto":["http"],"User-Agent":["Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"],"Accept":["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7"],"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":["1"],"Sec-Fetch-Mode":["navigate"],"Sec-Fetch-Dest":["document"],"X-Envoy-External-Address":["10.0.0.7"],"Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform":["\"macOS\""],"X-Appgw-Trace-Id":["1df4953e9788544fc1a4ede599a32efc"],"X-Original-Host":["my-external-url.com"],"X-Envoy-Expected-Rq-Timeout-Ms":["1800000"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0"],"X-K8se-App-Name":["app-www--3covj1h"],"X-K8se-App-Namespace":["k8se-apps"]}},"headers":{"Date":["Tue, 19 Dec 2023 17:05:43 GMT"]},"status":403}
```

Strangely, when I try to fetch the same proxied file from inside the `app-www` container using wget it works fine e.g.

```
# wget https://app-api.internal.somerandom-abc123.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io/content/d8e5a7fd-2330-42ca-949f-b4a5bc5b3dcc.png
```

Some things I have tried ...

- Making sure that the app is not scaled to zero.
- Using the app name (i.e. `https://app-api`) instead of the FQDN. For HTTP connections using the app name just hangs. For TCP ingress it works fine.
- Using unsecured http also does not work.

I'm going a bit nuts trying to solve this - its seems like a pretty basic confiuration (basically a SPA app plus API) but its just not working.

Caddyfile from `app-www` below

```
{
    auto_https off
    debug
}

(uselogin) {
    basicauth {
        {$PROXY_AUTH_CREDENTIALS}
    }
}

http://:80 {
    encode gzip
    header -Server
    header -X-Powered-By
    header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
    header X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"
    header X-Frame-Options: "SAMEORIGIN"

    handle /somepath/health-check {
        respond "health-check" 200
    }

    handle /somepath/* {
        import uselogin
        uri strip_prefix /somepath/
        # root * ./dist
        root * /srv/www
        try_files {path} /index.html
        file_server
    }

    handle /somepath/api/* {
        import uselogin
        uri strip_prefix /somepath/api
        reverse_proxy https://app-api.internal.somerandom-abc123.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io
    }

    handle * {
        respond 404
    }
}
```

Comment: Ensure that your Azure Container App's authentication settings are correctly configured for HTTP ingress. Double-check any authentication-related configurations in both app-www and app-api.